# Select country from a pop up in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, headless-ui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKwB1.png)

I want to implement the above screenshot. When I click on the country  dropdown, the default country name above plus the flag changes .
So far I have I have been using headless UI. The problem is that I dont know how to implement the logic in menu-item to change the default country and flag when dropdown is clicked, also the selectedactive country should be checked  .Below is my code ,someone help`

```
 import { Fragment, useState, useMemo, useEffect } from "react";
import Sidebar from "./sidebar";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import { Menu, Transition ,RadioGroup} from "@headlessui/react";
import { ChevronDownIcon } from "@heroicons/react/20/solid";
import { signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/react";



function classNames(...classes: any[]) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(" ");
}

const logout = () => {
  signOut();
};
const LayoutContent = ({
  children,
  sidebar,
}: {
  children: any;
  sidebar: any;
}) => {
  const { data: Session } = useSession();

  const [active,setActive] = useState(' ')

  return (

    
    <>
      <main
        className={`max-w-screen-3xl mx-auto flex  flex-col ${
          sidebar ? "lg:pl-20" : "lg:pl-80"
        }`}
      >
        <div className="pl-0 lg:mx-1">
          <nav className="mx-1 lg:mx-1 relative w-full flex flex-wrap items-center justify-end py-1 text-gray-800 ">
            

            <Menu as="div" className="relative inline-block text-left mr-5">
              <div>
                <Menu.Button className="inline-flex w-full items-center bg-white px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 ">
                  <Image
                    width={35}
                    height={35}
                    className="px-8 py-2.5"
                    src="/KE.svg"
                    alt="actions"
                  />
                  <span className="ml-4 text-gray-700 text-[13px]">Kenya</span>
                  <ChevronDownIcon
                    className="-mr-1 ml-2 h-7 w-7"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                  />
                </Menu.Button>
              </div>

              <Transition
                as={Fragment}
                enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
                enterFrom="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                enterTo="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                leaveFrom="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                leaveTo="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
              >

                
                <Menu.Items  className="absolute right-0 z-10 mt-2 w-56 h-48 bg-white  origin-top-right rounded-lg shadow-[0px_0px_28px_rgba(0,0,0,0.08)]  ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none">
                  <div className="py-1">
                    <span className="text-gray-500 ml-4 ">
                      Select Country
                    </span>
                    <Menu.Item>
                      {({ active}) => (
                        <a
                          href="#"
                          className={classNames(
                            active
                              ? " flex items-center text-gray bg-[#FDE6D4] rounded mb-3 ml-4 mr-4 mt-2"
                              : "flex items-center text-gray-500 bg-gray-100 rounded mb-3 ml-4 mr-4 mt-2 ",
                            "block px-4 py-2 text-sm"
                          )}
                        >
                          <Image
                            width={25}
                            height={25}
                            className="px-8 py-2.5"
                            src="/KE.svg"
                            alt="actions"
                          />
                          <span className="ml-4 text-[13px] ">Kenya</span>
                        </a>
                      )}
                    </Menu.Item>
                    <Menu.Item>
                      {({ active }) => (
                        <a
                          href="#"
                          className={classNames(
                            active
                              ? " flex items-center text-gray bg-[#FDE6D4] rounded mb-3 ml-4 mr-4"
                              : "flex items-center text-gray-500 bg-gray-100 rounded mb-3 ml-4 mr-4  ",
                            "block px-4 py-2 text-sm"
                          )}
                        >
                          
                          <Image
                            width={25}
                            height={25}
                            className="px-8 py-2.5"
                            src="/TZ (2).svg"
                            alt="actions"
                          />
                          <span className="ml-4 text-[13px]">Tanzania</span>
                          
                          
                        </a>
                      )}
                    </Menu.Item>
                    <Menu.Item>
                      {({ active}) => (
                        <a
                          href="#"
                          className={classNames(
                            active
                              ? " flex items-center text-gray bg-[#FDE6D4] rounded   ml-4 mr-4"
                              : " flex items-center text-gray-500 bg-gray-100 rounded ml-4 mr-4",
                            "block px-4 py-2 text-sm"
                          )}
                        >
                          <Image
                            width={25}
                            height={25}
                            className="px-8 py-2.5"
                            src="/MZ.svg"
                            alt="actions"
                          />
                          <span className="ml-4 text-[13px]">Mozambique</span>
                        </a>
                      )}
                    </Menu.Item>
                  </div>
                </Menu.Items>
              </Transition>
            </Menu>

            <p>
              <span className="px-0 py-2  text-gray-700 font-medium text-xs   focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:shadow-lg transition duration-150 ease-in-out flex items-center">
                <Image
                  width={25}
                  height={25}
                  className="p-2 rounded-full"
                  src="/rectangle.svg"
                  alt="Profile"
                />
              </span>
            </p>
            <p>
              <span className="px-1 py-2  text-gray-700 font-medium text-xs   focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:shadow-lg transition duration-150 ease-in-out flex items-center">
                {Session ? <p>{Session!.user!.name}</p> : "..."}
              </span>
            </p>
            <p>
              <span className="px-0 py-2  text-gray-700 font-medium text-xs   focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:shadow-lg transition duration-150 ease-in-out flex items-center mr-12">
                <Image
                  width={13}
                  height={13}
                  className="p-2 rounded-full"
                  src="/dropdown.svg"
                  alt="Profile"
                />
              </span>
            </p>
          </nav>
          {children}
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
};

export default LayoutContent;
```

`

I just implement headless UI without logic for updating the country and flag.What other options do I have ?

Comment: This question needs more focus - eg, to "change country and flag when dropdown is clicked", search for how to change something when an element is clicked (there are already answers for that). Likewise for other questions you have. StackOverflow is for problems that everyone has, not specific problems that you have.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to show the selected country at top right, you can try something like this

```
//data
const countries = [
 {
   id: 1, 
   src: "/KE.svg",
   label: "Kenya",
 },
 {
   id: 1, 
   src: "/TZ (2).svg",
   label: "Tanzania",
 }
 {
   id: 1, 
   src: "/MZ.svg",
   label: "Mozambique",
 }
]
```

Inside component

```
    // keep selected state
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState();

    // show selected country
   {
      selected ? 
      (
         <div>
                <Menu.Button className="inline-flex w-full items-center bg-white px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 ">
                  <Image
                    width={35}
                    height={35}
                    className="px-8 py-2.5"
                    src={selected.src}
                    alt="actions"
                  />
                  <span className="ml-4 text-gray-700 text-[13px]">{selected.label}</span>
                  <ChevronDownIcon
                    className="-mr-1 ml-2 h-7 w-7"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                  />
                </Menu.Button>
              </div>
      ) : null
   }
```

// display list of countries and on click select the country

```
   <Menu.Items  className="absolute right-0 z-10 mt-2 w-56 h-48 bg-white  origin-top-right rounded-lg shadow-[0px_0px_28px_rgba(0,0,0,0.08)]  ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none">
                      <div className="py-1">
                        <span className="text-gray-500 ml-4 ">
                          Select Country
                        </span>
                        {
                          data.map(country => {
    
                             return (
                               <Menu.Item key={country.id} 
                                  // if on click does not work here move to <a>
                                  onClick={e => setSelected(country)} 
                                  >
                                   {({ active}) => (
                                      <a
                                        href="#"
                                         className={classNames(
                                          active
                                  ? " flex items-center text-gray bg-[#FDE6D4] rounded mb-3 ml-4 mr-4 mt-2"
                                  : "flex items-center text-gray-500 bg-gray-100 rounded mb-3 ml-4 mr-4 mt-2 ",
                                "block px-4 py-2 text-sm"
                              )}
                            >
                              <Image
                                width={25}
                                height={25}
                                className="px-8 py-2.5"
                                src={country.src}
                                alt="actions"
                              />
                              <span className="ml-4 text-[13px] ">{country.label}</span>
                              </a>
                            )}
                            </Menu.Item>
                             )
    
                          });
                        }
                 </div>
    </Menu.Items>
```

Hope it helps you to find a better solution

Comment: HI Azzy ,I have tried to do the same thing you did and for some reason it ain't working. What options other than headless UI menu dropdown can I use to achieve what I want for countries ?